# How to get HttpContext Identity username in Audit.EntityframeworkCore

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am using **Audit.EntityFrameworkCore** Nuget package for auditing and I have the following configuration:

```
      Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup()
     .UseEntityFramework(ef => ef
         .UseDbContext<MyDbContext>(auditDbContextOptions)
         .AuditTypeMapper(t => typeof(DbChange))
         .AuditEntityAction<DbChange>((eventItem, entry, entity) =>
         {
             entity.TablePK = entry.PrimaryKey.Count == 1
                 ? entry.PrimaryKey.ElementAt(0).Value.ToString()
                 : JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entry.PrimaryKey);

             entity.TableName = entry.Table;
             entity.AuditAction = entry.Action;
             entity.AuditDate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
             entity.AuditData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entry);

             entity.AuditUser = eventItem.Environment.UserName;
             entity.RequestId = eventItem.GetEntityFrameworkEvent().ContextId;

         }).IgnoreMatchedProperties());
```

But **AuditUser** is coming as the Windows user not the user from the Identity of the HttpContext.

Answer (score 0):

I have added this configuration inside the startup class:

```
    Audit.Core.Configuration.AddOnCreatedAction(scope =>
    {
        var httpContextAccessor= scope.GetEntityFrameworkEvent().GetDbContext().GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
        var userName = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;
        scope.SetCustomField("UserName", userName);
        scope.Event.Environment.UserName = userName;
    });
```